# Как перевести многострочный текст с отступами в однострочный в Python?

Tags: python, строки, циклы

У меня такая проблема я пытаюсь перевести строчку введённую через `input()` к примеру:

> ```
> заказ
> пицца
> суши
> ```

перевести в:
`"заказ пицца суши"`, либо `"заказпиццасуши"`.

Я пробовал сделать так:

```py
text = ""
while True:
    x = input()
    if x:
       text += x + ""
    else:
        break
```

но он выдаёт только `"заказ"`.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Объясните как вы через функцию input() получаете строку с символом перевода строки?

Comment: Для этих целей можно использовать strip, replace и много чего ещё

Comment: https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-textwrap-python/funktsija-wrap-modulja-textwrap/

Comment: Я получил это через копирование готового текста

Comment: А вы потом в переменной `text` результат смотрите? Вообще-то всё должно работать по вашему описанию. Покажите лучше скриншот, как вы многострочный ввод делаете. А то тут много вариантов что могло пойти не так.

Comment: CrazyElf
Скриншот тут делать мне кажется бессмысленно, так как проблему я уже решил. Много строчный ввод я делал с помощью копирования(к примеру с какого-нибудь сайта). А text выводил первую строчку до отступа и всё.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно было сделать через графический интерфейс PyQt5
используя метод QLineEdit() - тогда введённый текст будет считаться в одну строчку.

Answer (score 0):

Для Питонa 3.8+ вы можете использовать оператор `:=`:

```
text = ""

while part := input():
    text += part
```

Этот код предполагает, что после ввода всех частей нажимете еще раз клавиш <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

*Обьяснение:*

- Выражение

  ```
  part := input()
  ```

  имеет то же самое значение, как выражение направо от оператора `:=`, т.е. то же самое, как выражение `input()`.
- Выражение `input()` - это введенная строка.
- Дла вычисления логического значения выражения в цикле `while` пустая строка имеет значение `False`, непустая `True`. Значит, цикл окночится вводом пустой строки.

Comment: Спасибо, я проверю

Comment: не совсем работает(та же проблема которая у меня была)

Comment: @anonimus, прежде чем я написал мой ответ, я мой код — как всегда — тестировал, и он работает. Ждет на ввод, я как пользователь напишу **заказ** и нажиму клавиш **Enter**, опят ждет ввода и я напишу **пицца** и **Enter**, опят ждет ввода и я напишу **суши** и **Enter**, затем уже не напишу ничего и только нажиму **Enter**. В переменной `text` будет строка `"заказпиццасуши"`.

Comment: @anonimius, в какой среде вы программу запускаете (напр. PyCharm, Jupyter, IDLE, онлайн тестер)?

Comment: Возможно я не правильно объяснил поэтому мне ваш код не подошёл, главное что проблему я решил, а пользуюсь я VisualStudioCode2022

Comment: @anonimus: *«...главное что проблему я решил...»*. Интересно. Ни какого «Извините меня все те, которые над моей проблемой напрасно трудились, что я вас своим вопросом ввел в заблуждение. Я на самом деле хотел что-то другое.»